# Improving speed with Ray-cast in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, raycasting

I am currently developing a lidar sensor model using Ray-cast. A 16 channel sensor rotating at 10Hz should produce 300000 points. I can use 300000 Ray-cast operations to get this result but the performance is very weak (frame rate falls to 8 when motion is given to the sensor). Is there any other better way or algorithms I can use?

Requirement :

- To scan 360 degrees: Horizontal
- -25 to 15 degrees: Vertical
- 300000 scans

Here is what I'm using:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < 3125; ++i){
  for (auto Channel = 0u; Channel < 16; ++Channel){
    FVector Point(0,0,0);
    float DistanceToHitPoint = 0;
    uint8_t Row = 0;
    uint8_t Class = 0u;
    double Intensity = 0;
    float Aoi = 0;
    const float Angle =  std::fmod(CurrentHorizontalAngle + AngleDistanceOfLaserMeasure * i,  360.0f);
    auto timestamp = static_cast<uint32_t>(GetEpisode().GetElapsedGameTime()* pow(10,6));
    ShootLaser(Channel, Angle, Point, DistanceToHitPoint, Row, Aoi, Class);
    if(Description.EnergyEffect && (DistanceToHitPoint != 0)){
        bool isQualified = IsPointIntensityValid(DistanceToHitPoint, Aoi, "test", Row, Intensity);
        LidarMeasurement.WritePoint(Channel, Point, Intensity, Class);
        LidarServer.fill_block(Angle, DistanceToHitPoint, Row, Description.ReturnMode, timestamp);
        continue;
    }
    LidarMeasurement.WritePoint(Channel, Point, Intensity, Class);
    LidarServer.fill_block(Angle, DistanceToHitPoint, Row, Description.ReturnMode, timestamp);

  }
}
const float HorizontalAngle = std::fmod(CurrentHorizontalAngle + AngleDistanceOfTick, 360.0f);
LidarMeasurement.SetHorizontalAngle(HorizontalAngle);
```

For 1500000 Raycast operation per second above code is used. I am trying to run the loops within 0.033 seconds(30fps). However, simulation fps turns out to be 2 or 3 fps after running this code. Is there any alternative to use Raycast more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

To simulate lidar you can use depth buffer of SceneCaptureComponent2D.

1. Create render target texture with format: RTF R16f
2. Create SceneCaptureComponent2D, assign target texture, set CaptureSource -> SceneDepth in R
3. Create Material with TextureObjectParameter, sample and divide by max_lidar_distance value in cm
4. Create DynamicMaterialInstance, set TextureParameterValue to target texture
5. Now you have scene depth rendered to texture, can be copied to main memory for other processing.

Check screenshots and example project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TImwJXmk5syvcPdPCylKXaaSCP99UI-m

Comment: Also check the CARLA project (open source vehicle simulation powered by ue4): https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cameras_and_sensors/#sensorcameradepth

Comment: I am trying to include physical effects to Lidar sensor in CARLA

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. But also I would like to know if it is possible to sample close to a million points just using raycast.

Comment: Software raycasting is deadend, imho. But anyway, check SceneQueryLowLevel.cpp LowLevelRaycast and PxBatchQuery.